# Convert C# Console application application to Website/WebApp

Tags: c#, web, console

I've made a console app (don't judge for it being badly written, I can't even do classes properly and I know that RegEx doesn't work with XML/HTML, but let's not mind that I'm not even a programmer)

```
        int retryCount = 0;
        int retryCount02 = 0;
        int innerpercentage = 1;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        HttpWebResponse response02 = null;
        //WebRequest groupingurl = WebRequest.Create("supersecretlink");
        WebRequest groupingurl = WebRequest.Create("anothersupersecretlink"); // temp
        var groupingurlread = (HttpWebResponse)groupingurl.GetResponse();
        using (var groupingreader = new StreamReader(groupingurlread.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            string responseGrouping = groupingreader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine("--------");
            var pattern = @"""ClassID"" Value=""(.*?)""";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(responseGrouping, pattern)
                .OfType<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                .ToArray();
            int percentage = 1;
            int percentagedone = matches.Length;

            foreach (string r in matches)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var url = "themostseriouslinkever";
                        string req = File.ReadAllText(@"somanylinksrighthere", Encoding.Default);
                        var go = url + req;
                        go = String.Format(go, r);
                        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(go);
                        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (WebException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Retry No. {0}", retryCount+1);
                        if (++retryCount < 3) continue; 
                        throw;  
                    }
                }
                retryCount = 0;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
                {



                    string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    pattern = @"<PartNumber>(.*?)</PartNumber>";
                    matches = Regex.Matches(responseText, pattern)
                              .OfType<Match>()
                              .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                              .ToArray();
                    int innerpercentagedone = matches.Length;
                    foreach (string bbb in matches)
                    {
                        // -----
                        //Console.WriteLine(bbb);
                        while (true)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var url02 = "anothersecret";
                                string req02 = File.ReadAllText(@"seeecreet", Encoding.Default);
                                var go02 = url02 + req02;
                                go02 = string.Format(go02, bbb);
                                WebRequest request02 = WebRequest.Create(go02);
                                response02 = (HttpWebResponse)request02.GetResponse();
                                break;
                            }
                            catch (WebException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Retry No. {0}", retryCount02+1);
                                if (++retryCount02 < 3) continue; 
                                throw;
                            }
                        }
                        retryCount02 = 0;
                        using (var reader02 = new StreamReader(response02.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
                        {
                            string responseText02 = reader02.ReadToEnd();
                            responseText02 = Regex.Replace(responseText02, (@"<\?xml.*\?>"), "");
                            //Console.WriteLine(responseText02);
                            //Console.WriteLine("</PartNumber>.*<");
                            responseText = Regex.Replace(responseText, ((@"<PartNumber>" + bbb + @"<\/PartNumber>")), responseText02);
                            //Console.WriteLine(responseText);
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("(" + percentage + ") " + innerpercentage + "/" + innerpercentagedone + ". Total: " + percentage + " / " + percentagedone);
                            innerpercentage++;
                        }
                    }


                    //string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Downloads\edasltxmlrequest\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\test\" + r + ".xml"))
                    {
                        outputFile.WriteLine(responseText);
                    }
                    //Console.Clear();
                    //Console.WriteLine(percentage + " / " + percentagedone);
                    percentage++;
                    innerpercentage = 1;
                    //Console.WriteLine(responseText);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("--------");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

So I wanted to ask if it's possible to make it run as a web app (http://www.amazingwebsite.com/ThisThingIWroteRightThere.php

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes.  Is it easy?  Depends on your skill level and knowledge of web apps.  As you say you're not even a programmer, you might find converting it to a web app a rather daunting task.

Comment: well i've never worked with web apps, and u can pretty much see my skill level on c# by looking at the script. and i did this by getting help from other people + internet

Comment: Also, maybe there any converters? Like c# to php, or c# to java...

Maybe it's just possible to build an app, which I could integrate to a website

Comment: you would probably find it much easier to learn asp.net and copy paste the relavent code. There is no simple way of converting this code to anything.